In the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ Assuming that $\angle BCD< 90^{\circ}$, prove that:$\angle DAB< 90^{\circ}$
In the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, with its side lengths $AB$, $BC, CD$,  are $25, 39, 52$, and $DA$ $60$ units, respectively. Assuming that $\angle BCD< 90^{\circ}$,

prove that:$\angle DAB< 90^{\circ}$.

Attempts:
By the cosine Low we get the following relations:
$$x^2=25^2+60^2-3000 \cos \alpha  \ \ \ \text{and } x^2=39^2+52^2-4056 \cos \beta$$
so we have
$$x^2=4225-3000 \cos \alpha $$ and $$x^2=4225-4056 \cos \beta$$
this means that
$$3000 \cos \alpha =4056 \cos \beta$$
Does anybody have any ideas on how to proceed?


Consider the sign of $\cos(\cdot)$ in the intervals of your interest.

@dfnu What does $~\cos(\cdot)~$ signify?

If $\angle BCD < 90^{\circ}$ then $BD^2 < CB^2+CD^2$
$BD^2 < AB^2+AD^2 = 25^2+60^2 = 39^2 + 52^2 = CB^2+CD^2$
hence $\angle BAD < 90^{\circ}$
In any $\triangle ABC$ (by cosine theorem)
If $BC^2 < AB^2+AC^2$ then $\angle BAC < 90^{\circ}$
If $BC^2 = AB^2+AC^2$ then $\angle BAC = 90^{\circ}$
If $BC^2 > AB^2+AC^2>BC^2$ then $\angle BAC > 90^{\circ}$


Considering this figure, suppose $\angle BCD=90^o$, then $BD\approx 62.7$
$cos BAD=\frac{62.7^2-25^2-60^2}{2\times 25\times 60}$
which gives :
$\angle BAD \approx 84^o$
This is the maximum of angle BDA. in relation:
$BC^2+CD^2-2BC\times CD cos BCD$
The decrease in angle BCD cause increase in value on $cos BCD$ ,therefore the measure of BD decreases which results in decrease of angle BAD.

In $\triangle BCD$, given fixed lengths $|CB|$ and $|CD|$, we know that the length $|BD|$ depends on angle $\widehat C$. The larger the angle, the longer the side in front of it (why?).
Now, the numbers given for side lengths are inspiring here.
If angle $\widehat C$ was $90^o$, then $\triangle BCD$ would be similar to the famous 3-4-5 right triangle, and $|BD|$ would be $5\times13 =65$. Interestingly, that would make $\triangle ABD$ similar to the famous 5-12-13 right triangle, which means angle $\widehat A$ would also be $90^o$.
However, the problem states that $\widehat C < 90^o$. It follows that $|BD| < 65$, which implies that $\widehat A < 90^o$.
